# C# list add works but not append?

Tags: c#, list, append

I'm using C# System.Collections.Generic List and the Add function works as expected but Append does nothing? Why is this? I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't see what, I use it the same as Add but it doesn't work?

```
List<string> x = new List<string>();
x.Add("hello");
foreach (string s in x) { Console.WriteLine(s); }
Console.WriteLine();
x.Add("hi");
foreach (string s in x) { Console.WriteLine(s); }
Console.WriteLine();
x.Append("oi");
foreach (string s in x) { Console.WriteLine(s); }
Console.WriteLine();
x.Append("aye");
foreach (string s in x) { Console.WriteLine(s); }
Console.WriteLine();
```

output:

```
hello

hello
hi

hello
hi

hello
hi
```

Comment: Searching online for *"c# SomeMethodName"* will usually bring you to the documentation for the method that isn't working the way you expect it to. There you can read about how to use it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.8) returns the updated collection, instead of modifying the original.

The correct use would be something like `var y = x.Append("foo")`. Note that you cannot store the result of `Append` back in `x`, since it returns a reference of type `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `List<string>`.

In general, I would stick with using `List<string>.Add(string)`, unless you are actually dealing with an `IEnumerable<T>` object.

Comment: Is there a way to add to the beginning or would I have to add a null element to the list, then shift everything and place my new element at the end? Thank you so much for the help btw

Comment: You can use the [`List<T>.Insert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.8) method to insert anywhere in the list. To insert in the beginning, use index `0`, like: `x.Insert(0, "greetings");`

Comment: @mizuprogrammer There is also an accompanying [Prepend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.8) method, which will add the item to the start of the enumerable.

Comment: Side note: "Append returns the updated collection" is not exactly true - it returns enumerable that will have an extra item at the end of the source collection *at the time of enumeration*.  I.e. `var x = new List<int>{1,2,3};
var y = x.Append(4);
x.Add(5); var list = y.ToList();` will result in list = "1,2,3,5,4" (and not 1,2,3,4 which even if `Append` called on the list of 1,2,3).

Comment: Thank you so much for saving my sanity with this answer and restoring my faith in S.O.! 
Having written something not dissimilar to what the OP posted, I've just had a very heated debate with a certain talkative AI tool which was too busy telling me what I should do (call Add()) and that my code couldn't possibly compile. Erm...